# Xamarin select a pixel in the center of the photo

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application and I want to do things with the pixel in the image.

[image]

I take 3 pictures and show them like this. When I click on the sender;

My aim is to determine the color code of the pixels in the middle of these photographs.

For example: I would like to return a positive response if the pixel color code in the middle of the photos is #007f00. Every center pixel in the 3 photos should be equal.

This is my photo-taking code.

```
private async void btnPhoto1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                DisplayAlert("UYARI", "Cihazınızın kamerası aktif değil!", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
                new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "MediaPluginPhoto",
                    Name = DateTime.Now + ".jpg",
                    DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front
                });

            if (file == null)
                return;


            img1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                file.Dispose();
                return stream;
            });
        }
```

On the other hand, all the pixels in the photo can be counted. If the number of pixels with color code # 007f00 is more than 1000 degrees, I can get a positive answer.

Those who have developed similar examples before, please help. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this on natively on Android, but if you get your image to a byte array, then get the color of the pixel, like this.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

Color x = bitmap.GetPixel(width / 2, height / 2);
```

I assume you already have the height and width of the image, you just need to divide by 2, to get the center.

imageBytes is just the image converted to a byte array.

To get the imageBytes from the stream, you can do this:

```
var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
photo.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);

var imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't understand. For my code; img is a Image and I want to learn center  pixel code. When I edit that;      'Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(img1, 0, img1.Length);

            Color x = bitmap.GetPixel(Width / 2, Height / 2);'  I take error img1.Length.

Comment: I am so sorry but I still have not found a solution. I also shared all my codes with github. All I want is to click the analyze button, the pixel at the center of the loaded image, the button text to write. /*GitHub Link : https://github.com/sluggish144/Welon/issues/1 */

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you how to convert the stream, into a byte array.

Comment: You're right, Adam, we solved my problem with my friend. Thank you so much. I took a problem converting the Image to Bitmap. Now, we solve.